# Emitter circuit on a breadboard

Tags: ltspice, simulation, oscilloscope, breadboard, common-emitter

I am working on an emitter circuit that has a 2N3904 NPN transistor.

I have simulated the circuit before and got the results. I am trying to build it in the lab so I can compare the results to my simulation.

I am not sure what I am missing because it feels like I did something wrong. I replicated the breadboard in Tinkercad so that you have an idea of what it looks like.

P.S. Sorry, I know it is a messy one, I am a bit out of practice on breadboards.

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Your breadboard software shows C and E swapped from what it actually is for a 2N3904. Check the datasheet and use the pinouts there as a basis for your wiring.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, yes I did correct in the software, but on the Breadboard it was correct. also I connected he other side of C to the emiter. I still dont get the but still my Ch1 isn't getting any better.

Comment: Try to remove C3 and Re’. It rapidly increases the gain so circuit works like switch, not an amp.

Comment: What is an "emitter circuit"? Do you  mean "common-emitter circuit"? Note that "common-emitter circuit" doesn't mean "a common circuit" (although it is actually pretty common), it means something more like "a circuit in which the emitter is 'commoned' (aka grounded - sort-of)".

Comment: Remove C3 and Re initially .|| Try a much lower frequency initially. Observe.

Comment: I have tried removing the C3 and Re but the results wasn't what I expected. and this circuit should be fully functional as it is. ( I got it from a University's script)  I have edited the updated pictures, I would like to know if you believe it is an accurate demonstration of the Simulaiton. I would highly appreciate it.

Comment: @BenMüller Another question. A signal generator usually has a 50 ohm output impedance (some have settings, though, that can change it to things like CMOS or TTL, for example.) So, because it expects 50 ohm termination the generator outputs a voltage that is twice the setting value. Did you measure the unloaded signal generator output using a high impedance scope setting (not the 50 ohm setting)? (I'm talking here about reality, not simulation.) Details matter.

Answer (score 1):

You show 0.1V input in the simulation, yet ~5V on the breadboard. The waveform appears to be normal operation for such heavy overdrive.  You will observe shifts in bias voltages for the same reason.

Simply reducing the input voltage will get the expected result, and bias voltages should match within reason.

Comment: I have adjusted the Inputs Amplitude and I got a similar results, Thank you.  Would you say that the replication from the simulation is accurate?

Comment: I would need to see more nodes' measurements and more detail to tell exact differences, but yes that looks much better.

Answer (score 0):

Your amplifier seems to be working. The problem is that your output signal is too large. The output needs to be within the range of the supply voltage. The gain is ~180, which gives an output of +/-18V for a 0.1V input. You would probably need a 40V power supply to handle this output. Try removing Re', which will reduce the gain to ~10. You should see better agreement with simulation then.

Comment: I have removed Re, The Sin waves became more flat than round, and I adjusted the Amplitude through Function generator. but the end results is exactly the same as with it. So without the Re I have the Same image as above on the Oscilloscope

Comment: You removed Re', right? The 82-ohm resistor?

Comment: at first I made a mistake and removed the 1.5k but I just did the 8.2 ohm and still it looks the same. Is it normal that when I remove C the 100uF capacitor nothing changes? I even tried replacing it. Because I feel that could be the reason why when I remove the Re (82 Ohm) I get the same results as with ReI dont even need to change anything to the Function generator.         I really appreciate the help

Comment: Removing the 100uF capacitor should mess up your DC bias. To be clear, is the yellow trace (channel 1) the output node? What do you see when you scope the collector voltage directly?

Comment: @BenMüller You just wrote above about removing the `8.2 ohm` resistor. But your question shows 82, not 8.2. Which were you using, in reality? Details ***do*** matter.

Comment: @AdamHaun channel 1 is connected to Ca (Output), and I do have to check the voltage scope once I get in the lab.

Comment: @periblepsis It's 82Ohm, I made a mistake typing. I remeasured before commenting yesterday.

Comment: @BenMüller One goal is to have \$I_{_{\text{C}_\text{Q}}}\cdot R_{_{\text{E}_\text{AC}}}\gg V_T\$. This helps to keep the voltage gain stable. \$V_T\approx 26\:\text{mV}\$. I figure that you have \$I_{_{\text{C}_\text{Q}}}\approx 400\:\mu\text{A}\$. So \$I_{_{\text{C}_\text{Q}}}\cdot R_{_{\text{E}_\text{AC}}}\approx 33\:\text{mV}\$. That is a problem as \$\require{cancel}33\:\text{mV}\cancel{\gg} 26\:\text{mV}\$. Do you understand this? This is a fundamental problem with your design. (I don't care if it is given to you on a silver platter from a professor. It is a problem, regardless.)

Comment: @BenMüller There are also signal level issues here that I've avoided for the moment. But the point remains. You should ***expect*** both thermal and also signal-related distortion problems given the situation you show. This is ***not*** a good design. You should not be surprised at all when things look wrong, in practice. (And I still need to know if you checked the signal generator output. That's yet another detail to learn about.)

Comment: @BenMüller Haven't seen an update on this, but I really think that your gain is just too high. Try designing for a gain of 2 to start with. Measure the DC voltage at base, collector, and emitter to verify that they're what you expect, then scope the collector voltage.

Comment: Hey, sorry guys I edited the images and I thought I sent a comment. Adam you were right. I put the power supply on 30V instead of 15 and that was one of the reasons my circuit wasn't functioning as intended. the other reason was from the way I previously built it.  I pulled everything out and did it again and it worked as intended as you can see in the updated images.